# Android display boolean from Retrofit as false ALWAYS

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2, android-json

In my Main Activity i execute SincronizacionDb to compare the data between SQLite and the MYSQL Server, however the json_array retrieved works fine, it's show true or false if the data it's different from the server, but in the APP, this value seems to be always false.

**SincronizacionDb**

```
private void sincronizacionDB() {
    if (dbCheck(MainActivity.this, "beneficiosColaborador.db")) {
        int size = sqLiteHandler.getLastIdBeneficio();
        Call<VersionDb> versionDb = restManager.getApiService().checkServerDatabaseVersion(size);
        versionDb.enqueue(new Callback<VersionDb>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<VersionDb> call, Response<VersionDb> response) {
                Log.e("RESPONSE", "CALLING ON RESPONSE");
                VersionDb version = response.body();
                isOutdate = version.getEstado();
                Log.i("VERSION", "RESPUESTA" + version.getEstado()); // Get the value from GSon(TRUE, FALSE) WORKS PERFECT
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<VersionDb> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
        Log.e("outdate","" + isOutdate); // ALWAYS FALSE
        if (isOutdate) {
            sqLiteHandler.deleteBeneficio();
            Log.e("Beneficios", "Se han eliminado los beneficios viejos");
            Call<List<Beneficios>> callBeneficios = restManager.getApiService().getListadoBeneficios();
            callBeneficios.enqueue(new Callback<List<Beneficios>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Beneficios>> call, Response<List<Beneficios>> response) {
                    List<Beneficios> beneficioData = response.body();
                    sqLiteHandler.addListBeneficios(beneficioData);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Beneficios>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }else{
        Call<List<Beneficios>> callBeneficios = restManager.getApiService().getListadoBeneficios();
        callBeneficios.enqueue(new Callback<List<Beneficios>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Beneficios>> call, Response<List<Beneficios>> response) {
                List<Beneficios> beneficioData = response.body();
                sqLiteHandler.addListBeneficios(beneficioData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Beneficios>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: EXAMPLE JSON TRUE]

[image: EXAMPLE JSON FALSE]

and the Results i got in the ANDROID MONITOR

```
    08-11 08:39:31.417 13618-13618/com.freelance.crdzbird_dev.clarobadge D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching LAST ROW from Sqlite: 213
08-11 08:39:31.617 13618-13618/com.freelance.crdzbird_dev.clarobadge E/outdate: false
08-11 08:39:31.867 13618-13618/com.freelance.crdzbird_dev.clarobadge E/RESPONSE: CALLING ON RESPONSE
08-11 08:39:31.867 13618-13618/com.freelance.crdzbird_dev.clarobadge I/VERSION: RESPUESTA true
```

Please someone explain me how to avoid this error :(

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that updates the value of `isOutdate`... where are you changing it?

Comment: Sorry, i updated the question, the value i got it fromVersionDb.getEstado

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are doing an asynchrounous call in here :

```
versionDb.enqueue(new Callback<VersionDb>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<VersionDb> call, Response<VersionDb> response) {
                Log.e("RESPONSE", "CALLING ON RESPONSE");
                VersionDb version = response.body();
                isOutdate = version.getEstado();
                Log.i("VERSION", "RESPUESTA" + version.getEstado()); // Get the value from GSon(TRUE, FALSE) WORKS PERFECT
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<VersionDb> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

And your value of `isOutdate` is initialized at false, so it will be always false since it executes the check before returning from the service.

So either wait for your callback or use the synchronized method `execute` in retrofit.